# How to plot separate bar in bar graph for repeated values using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked

Given a dataset:

```
x = [3, 2, 4, 6, 7]
y = ['a','a','b','b','c']
```

Here variables `a` and `b` are repeated twice. My requirement is to plot the bar graph for each variable and for variables a and b, we need a separate bar for each a and b.

I was trying to plot a horizontal bar graph using the code:

```
plt.barh(y, x)
```

[image: Horizontal Barplot of dataset]

Here the value of `a` and `b` are stacked and plotted in a single bar. Please help with this.

Comment: I could not understand the requirement of your question correctly. So if you need to plot a bar graph based upon the repetition of the variables in `y`, what do you need `x` for?

Comment: x is the value associated on the x-axis with each value of y I want to plot. I don't want to count the number of times a specific value in y has appeared @AmirhosseinKiani

Comment: @AlexisG, No I don't think so. The link you have shared is to plot two different bars on the same axis without an overlap which is a different case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot on a range and change the tick labels:

```
x = [3, 2, 4, 6, 7]
y = ['a','a','b','b','c']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.barh(range(len(x)), x)
plt.yticks(range(len(x)), y)
```

output:

[image]